# Cant set session variable to stable value on reloading the page

Tags: php

I'm making a php app. I used sessions for splitting users
for example:

```php
<?php
session_start();
?>
<?php
$_SESSION["color"] = random_int(1, 2);
?>
```

I want to became a not changeable and unique value but on refresh it would change its value.
For example:

```
1,2,1,1,2,1,2,2,1
```

please help.

Comment: I'm confused by your question.  Why are you using a random_int if you don't want it to be random?

Comment: tiw! i want to be a number between 0 & 3. if you have any suggestion please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP session variables are not immutable.  You will need to check for the value being set already before setting it to something else.  Notice that `isset` will only work for variables that are not null, `array_key_exists` maybe more suitable depending on what data is being stored.

```
if (!isset($_SESSION["color"])) {
    $_SESSION["color"] = random_int(1, 2);
}
```